# User Check-In History in Visual Studio 2012 / 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, team-explorer

In Visual Studio 2010, I was able to view the check-in history of a particular user from 
`Team Explorer -> Team Project -> Team Members -> Right-click on a user name -> Show Check-in History`.

I just can't find such option in Visual Studio 2012/2013 after the drastic Team Explorer UI re-design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should install TFS Power tools 2012 (download [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f)).
[image: Team Members]

> However, the Team Members Power Tool was changed to take advantage of
>   new TFS 2012 features.  As such it is incompatible with TFS 2010 and
>   earlier and does not run off the same team member definition data as
>   the TFS 2010 Team Members Power Tool, making using the VS 2010 IDE and
>   VS 2012 IDE together with the Team Members Power Tool a bit of a pain
>   (double administration).

Comment: How does one actually go about finding this window once Power Tools 2012 is installed?

Comment: I downvoted this answer because although I have TFS Power Tools 2012, I still cannot see a checkin history for a particular user.

Comment: Here I am almost exactly 6 months later with the exact same problem..  And I find this answer and find that I already commented on it...

Answer (score 31):

You can achive this functionality trough Source Control Explorer. Right mouse button click on folder in Source Control Explorer, then select Find / Find Changeset. In this window on image below you can select user and see only changesets by this pariticular user.

[image]

Comment: Well, this is the one that works for me, but technically Cybermaxs's answer is better.

Comment: Cybermaxx's answer requires you have installed another software (be it a plugin or an extension of VS), thus not su much valid as an intrinsic solution such as Antonio's.

Comment: Once in the Source Control Explorer, you can use the `Ctrl`+`G`, `Ctrl`+`G` shortcut to open the Find Changesets window.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same goal via tf.exe

> tf history * /user:username -R

* means all files and -R means recursive.

If you want to it display only command line (better for exporting), just type

> tf history * /user:username -R /noprompt

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio Professional 2015, Team Explorer->Team Foundation Server (TFS),double click in the TFS server link then provide user Name and Password, click OK -> click Code  on top -> click Changesets-> provide author Name.