# Team members power tools 2012 with TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools

I have visual studio 2012 installed with TFS 2010. I installed power tools 2012 recently but I do not see the Team Members tab.

Is there compatibility issue between TFS 2010 and VS 2012?
If yes, any work around to see the Team Members tab in VS 2012 with TFS 2010?

I referred to the below link and it seems there are compatibility issues. Any work around?

[User Check-In History in Visual Studio 2012 / 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685926/user-check-in-history-in-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `Power tools 2010` by `Command Line`, or add External Tool (Section Tools) in your Visual Studio.

link : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2010/04/23/tfs-2010-power-tools-are-now-available.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can install the 2010 and the 2012 versions of the power tools side-by-side as long as only one version of the Windows Explorer Extensions and the Powershell cmd-lets is installed.

If you want integration into Visual Studio 2012, you must install the 2012 version of the power tools. Some features (like the Create Project option of tfpt) might require you to use the version that matches the TFS version,which is why you'd do a side-by-side installation.

The Team Members tab in the [Team Foundation Server Power Tools 2012 and up only work against server 2012 and up, due to changes in the datamodel used to define Teams](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2014/01/Install-Team-Foundation-Server-Power-Tools-side-by-side.html).